# Что такое плашки и как это сделать?

Tags: html5

Написать страничку которая будет передвигать плашки по нажатию на кнопку вперед или назад

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let x = 10;
forward.addEventListener('click', () => (x += 20, плашка.style.transform = `translateX(${x}px)`));
backward.addEventListener('click', () => (x -= 20, плашка.style.transform = `translateX(${x}px)`));
```

```html
<button id="forward">вперед</button><button id="backward">назад</button><br>
<img id="плашка" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bpTd.jpg">
```